# SQL Query to split in start/end with desire output

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a table with below records

| ItemCode | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.000 |
| 1 | 0.290 |
| 1 | 0.370 |
| 1 | 0.650 |
| 1 | 1.190 |
| 1 | 2.120 |
| 1 | 2.700 |
| 1 | 2.900 |
| 1 | 7.360 |
| 2 | 2.340 |
| 2 | 2.790 |
| 2 | 2.890 |
| 2 | 3.500 |
| 2 | 3.600 |
| 3 | 2.100 |
| 3 | 2.250 |
| 3 | 3.000 |

I would like to output as below

| ItemCode | BeginNum | EndNum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.000 | 0.290 |
| 1 | 0.290 | 0.370 |
| 1 | 0.370 | 0.650 |
| 1 | 0.650 | 1.190 |
| 1 | 1.190 | 2.120 |
| 1 | 2.120 | 2.700 |
| 1 | 2.700 | 2.900 |
| 1 | 2.900 | 7.360 |
| 2 | 2.340 | 2.790 |
| 2 | 2.790 | 2.890 |
| 2 | 2.890 | 3.500 |
| 2 | 3.500 | 3.600 |
| 3 | 2.100 | 2.250 |
| 3 | 2.250 | 3.000 |

Comment: sorry, I should have posted my query I tried. This was my first post. Will keep in mind for future post. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `lead()`:

```
select *
from (
    select itemcode, value as num, 
        lead(value) over(partition by itemcode order by value) as endnum
    from mytable 
) t
where endnum is not null
```

Note that this eliminates the last record per group, as shown in your sample data.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it too (if you want the last record by group, replace 'inner join' by 'left outer join') :

```
with tablewithrow as (
select f1.*, row_number() over(partition by f1.ItemCode order by (select null)) rang 
from mytable f1  
)

select f1.ItemCode, f1.Value BeginNum, f2.Value EndNum
from tablewithrow f1
inner join tablewithrow f2 on f1.ItemCode=f2.ItemCode and f1.rang=f2.rang - 1
```